# javascript: searching for text

Tags: javascript

i have an input tag that i use to search for text in the page.
I have this javascript:

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
    if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
    var strFound;
    if (window.find) {

        // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find
        strFound=self.find(str);
        if (!strFound) {
            strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
            while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
        }
    }
    else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

        // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

        if (TRange!=null) {
            TRange.collapse(false);
            strFound=TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
        if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
            TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
            strFound=TRange.findText(str);
            if (strFound) TRange.select();
        }
    }
    else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
        $('#srchform2').hide();
        alert ("Il browser opera non è supportato")
        return;
    }
    if (!strFound) alert ("testo non trovato!")
    return;
}
```

when it found a word it point out that with gray color!
How can i change this color?

Comment: i haven't tried anything! i don't know what to do!  this code works fine to find the word but highlight them in gray! i want that he highlight them in yellow!

Comment: It's probably a system color..  You'd have to implement your own highlighting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your browser it might or might not be supported. Here is essentially what you can do:

```
::selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
        }
::-moz-selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}

::-webkit-selection {
  background:#cc0000;  /* Webkit */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS in modern browsers to change the color of selected text:

```
::-moz-selection{ background: #080; color:#fff;}
::selection { background:#080; color:#fff; }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GUC5d/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your question is actually: How do I change the color of selected text?

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html

However, if what you are really trying to do is highlight the found word, you probably want to wrap the found word in a `<span>` element with a CSS class that highlights to your preference.  That way the highlight won't be lost when the user selects something else.